# What does the keyword this refer to when used as a function parameter/agrument?

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm somewhat past the newbie stage of javascript and am looking at how a certain widget library works. (All printed out code, can't copy and paste) I condensed it so I hope it's enough for you guys to understand.

```
Page.prototype.createForm= function (){
    ....
    this.form1 = new Form(); 
    ....
    this.form1.clickEvent(this,"clickedDelete"); 
};

Page.prototype.clickedDelete= function (){
     ....
};
```

So my question is what the this inside ClickEvent mean? 
this.Form.clickEvent(this,"clickedDelete")

I hope this is enough information, but anyways, what is this inside

```
 (this,"clickedDelete")
```

referring to?

is it the page object or page.form1 (thus called this.form1?)

If this is too little information, can you provide any links or examples of your own that's somewhat close to this example. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on how the function is invoked. You need to show us that.

Comment: @Quentin: You're technically correct, but one could reasonably assume that `Page.prototype.createForm` is called on an instance of `Page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to whatever object the currently executing function is called on -- in your example, it is the `Page` object, assuming it is called along the lines of `page.createForm()`.

Comment: Oh, so just to make sure, if it's inside the clickedDelete function, would this refer to Page.form1 then instead?

Comment: @Ali: `clickedDelete` is still a method of `Page`, so `this` would refer to the page. `clickEvent`, on the other hand, is a method of `form1`, so inside this method `this` would refer to `form1`.